# VBA access remote website, automate clicking submit after already automating clicking button on other webpage

Tags: vba, web, automation, click, remote-server

I'm working with vba in excel 2010 and internet explorer 8 and Vista.  The code below works to go to a remote website and post a form.  On the resulting page, the code should click the "get estimates" button.  Instead I get this error "object variable or with block variable not set".  The highlighted problem line in the code is "estimate = ieApp.document.getElementById("btnRequestEstimates")".

I think part of the problem might be that the button that isn't working is a submit button that isn't part of a form.  I am also wondering if the variables need to be reset before the 2nd button click.  The error message implies this is a qualification problem, but I think it's a pretty standard way of qualifying an element in this situation.  Those are some things I've been googling to no avail, I'm not really sure what the problem is.

```
Sub btn_version()

Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieForm As Object
Dim ieObj As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim estimate As Object

URL = "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/p-2688-new-testament-cricut-cartridge.aspx"
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.navigate URL
While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Set ieDoc = ieApp.document
Set ieForm = ieDoc.forms(1)
For Each ieObj In ieForm.Elements
If ieObj.ClassName = "AddToCartButton" Then
ieObj.Click
End If
Next ieObj

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
estimate = ieApp.document.getElementById("btnRequestEstimates")
estimate.submit
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing "Set". And submit is a form method, not applicable to a button. You probably want to use the click method there...

Answer (score 3):

The code below combines your xmlhttp code from [automate submitting a post form that is on a website with vba and xmlhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8798661/641067) (to give you better control on the `POST`, ie skipping your `Set ieDoc = ieApp.document` section in our question) with clicking the `"btnRequestEstimates` button on the final URl from [this page](https://www.craft-e-corner.com/ShoppingCart.aspx?add=true&ReturnUrl=showproduct.aspx%3fProductID%3d2688%26SEName%3dnew-testament-cricut-cartridge)

```
Sub Scrape2()

Dim objIE As Object
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim ieButton As Object
Dim strResponse As String
Dim strUrl As String

strUrl = "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/addtocart.aspx?returnurl=showproduct.aspx%3fProductID%3d2688%26SEName%3dnew-testament-cricut-cartridge"
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.navigate "about:blank"
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'~~> Indicates that page that will receive the request and the type of request being submitted
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/addtocart.aspx?returnurl=showproduct.aspx%3fProductID%3d2688%26SEName%3dnew-testament-cricut-cartridge", False
'~~> Indicate that the body of the request contains form data
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'~~> Send the data as name/value pairs
xmlhttp.Send "Quantity=1&VariantID=2705&ProductID=2688"
strResponse = xmlhttp.responseText
objIE.navigate strUrl
objIE.Visible = True

Do While objIE.readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

objIE.document.Write strResponse

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
Set ieButton = objIE.document.getelementbyid("btnRequestEstimates")
ieButton.Click

End Sub
```