# Recognize a button on a website using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, authentication, navigation

I've been trying to create logins for my work processes. Some websites work.

This link is ALMOST an answer except ieObj is not defined. [vba automation in Internet Explorer - clicking different buttons on successive webpages not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826097/vba-automation-in-internet-explorer-clicking-different-buttons-on-successive-w)

Here's what I have. Pared down. *Italics* are variable references. 
Normally this works great. The button on this website Doesn't have a "name" though.  Just a Class, Onclick, and Title (but the title is "" null).  I've tried .getelementbytagName(Button), .getelementbyclassname("ButtonThemeA") and a slew of other things.  It always errors at the button click section.

How do I reference this button and click it?

I get a Run-Time Error '438'; Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub Login1()

    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim LoginVal As String
    Dim PassVal As String
    Dim ieForm As Object
    Dim ieObj As Object


    'create a new instance of ie
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

    'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
    ieApp.Visible = True

    'Login Screen
    ieApp.Navigate "*webpage to login*"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'Get the login values
    LoginVal = Workbooks("Macrobook").Sheets("Login").Cells(2, 3).Value
    PassVal = Workbooks("Macrobook").Sheets("Login").Cells(2, 4).Value
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

    'fill in the login form
    With ieDoc
        .getElementById("usr_name").Value = LoginVal
        .getElementById("usr_password").Value = PassVal
        .getElementbyTagName(button).Click
    End With
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'To acct list screen
    ieApp.Navigate "*Acct list URL - Not important for this question*"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    'And it goes on from here.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the "submit" button, you don't need the name (or ID of that button). What you need is the Form "id". Then you can just say: `iedocument.form("formname").submit`

I use it in this way:

```
Sub website_newtitle()

    target_form = "model-node-form" '<-- THE FORM ID      
    target_url = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("models").Cells(1, 1).Value
    new_title = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("models").Cells(1, 2).Value

    'Modification
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim LookUpValue As String
    Dim HtmlDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim SubmitInput As HTMLInputElement

    ie.Navigate target_url
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'wait till the page is loaded
    Loop

    Set HtmlDoc = ie.document

    With ie
        .Visible = True 'disable to remain invisible
        .AddressBar = True
        .Toolbar = True
    End With

    HtmlDoc.forms(target_form).elements("edit-title").Value = new_title

    'submit data
    HtmlDoc.Forms(target_form).Submit '<-- SUBMIT THE FORM
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'wait till the page is loaded

     'close window
     ie.Quit
End Sub
```