# Is there a way to call a Google API from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, google-api, google-calendar-api, vba

I want to pass some cell values from excel to a google calender API.Is there a way for this?

Comment: You can POST data from VBA using an XMLHTTP object. Eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798661/automate-submitting-a-post-form-that-is-on-a-website-with-vba-and-xmlhttp

Comment: This site has many, many examples http://www.mcpher.com/ albeit at an advanced user level. But includes demos, code etc. it may help you.