# VBA - Dictionary Calling Key by Value?

Tags: vba, outlook

It seems most of the answers for this involve C# so I felt relatively safe asking:

I need to call a dictionary key by it's value. I have a dictionary object with a list of four character keys. For Example:

```
dSCAC.Add "AAAA", 1
dSCAC.Add "BBBB", 2
dSCAC.Add "CCCC", 3
dSCAC.Add "DDDD", 4
```

etc.

I've been able to call the value associated with a key when it's found in a string (in this case, an email subject line) and then add or remove 1 from the value.

Ex: BBBB is detected, value is 2. Modify the value and call the appropriate key. In this case, in the end we'd want varOtherSCAC = AAAA.

```
If dSCAC(varSCAC) Mod 2 Then
        Debug.Print "Odd " & "PAPS"
        varOtherSCAC = (dSCAC(varSCAC) + 1)            
        Debug.Print "Opposite SCAC is " & varOtherSCAC

        Else
        Debug.Print "Even " & " PARS"
        varOtherSCAC = (dSCAC(varSCAC) - 1)
        Debug.Print "Opposite SCAC is " & varOtherSCAC
End if
```

I haven't been able to work out the syntax for calling the new key based on this value. Is it even possible in VBA? Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is the use case for this? A dictionary typically only ensures that the *key* is unique - do you need both the key and the value to be unique?  If not, is there a rule as to which key you would return if there are duplicates?

Comment: I currently have a few little projects on the go and for convenient updating have created the dictionary as a central place for all the codes I need to check against/verify are correct/present in a string. In this case, when I discover a legal code I want to be able to quickly call its associated one (which can then be added to a new string and printed). If BBBB is in the string, I want to be able to find its counterpart; AAAA in this case. Each key/value would have to be unique, yes. AAAA would always only be 1, BBBB only ever 2, etc.

Comment: Unique key/value pairs aren't really the same thing as unique *values*.  To rephrase the question, is there only one 1, only one 2, etc.

Comment: Yes, there's only one of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take similar approach to @TateGarringer's, but wrap the two `Dictionary` objects in a class to give them a common interface and make the thing easier to use:

```
'In a class module named MirroredDictionary.cls (add reference to Scripting Runtime)
Option Explicit

Private backing As Scripting.Dictionary
Private mirror As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set backing = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set mirror = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Key As Variant, Value As Variant)
    backing.Add Key, Value
    mirror.Add Value, Key
End Sub

Public Function KeyExists(Key As Variant) As Boolean
    KeyExists = backing.Exists(Key)
End Function

Public Function ValueExists(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    ValueExists = mirror.Exists(Value)
End Function

Public Function ValueFromKey(Key As Variant) As Variant
    ValueFromKey = backing.Item(Key)
End Function

Public Function KeyFromValue(Value As Variant) As Variant
    KeyFromValue = mirror.Item(Value)
End Function
```

Depending on how you intend to use this, you may or may not want to wrap additional functions. Usage would be similar to a normal `Dictionary` (aside from some differences in the property names, although you can change those to taste):

```
Public Sub Example()
    Set sample = New MirroredDictionary

    sample.Add "AAAA", 1
    sample.Add "BBBB", 2
    sample.Add "CCCC", 3
    sample.Add "DDDD", 4

    Debug.Print sample.ValueFromKey("AAAA")     '1
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(1)          'AAAA
    Debug.Print sample.ValueFromKey("BBBB")     '2
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(2)          'BBBB
    Debug.Print sample.ValueFromKey("CCCC")     '3
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(3)          'CCCC
    Debug.Print sample.ValueFromKey("DDDD")     '4
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(4)          'DDDD
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the idea of a common interface, but I've never dealt with class modules before so it might take a little while for me to wrap my head around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kinote This would be the perfect opportunity to play with them.  ;-)  Stepping through the sample code line by line in the debugger will give you a pretty good idea of how it works.  You're basically implementing your own custom dictionary class.

Comment: Compile Error: User-defined type not defined when I hit the class module - when it hits the first line `Private backing As Scripting.Dictionary`  - Might all be a little above my head, syntax wise. The concept of the double dictionary does indeed solve my issue, the syntax for making it work... that'll take a while. I kind of stumbled into getting my current one working when my other modules interact with it.

Comment: @Kinote That's the comment at the top - you either need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (better) or [change it to late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50583705/4088852).

Comment: Ah. Kind of figured that's what I was missing. How would I go about adding a reference to the MSR? Apologies for all the rookie questions!

Comment: Tools -> References... find Microsoft Scripting Runtime (scroll *way* down), check the box, then hit [OK].  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Found it! Code seems to run just fine now and looks very interesting, I'll tinker with it a bit when I get some time. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Any idea why it only works in the third case? `'Test 1 - Doesn't work
    Dim strTestSCACValue As String: strTestSCACValue = "3"
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(strTestSCACValue)
    'Test 2 - Doesn't work
    Dim intTestSCACValue: intTestSCACValue = "3"
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(intTestSCACValue)
    'Test 3 - Works
    intTestSCACValue = 3
    Debug.Print sample.KeyFromValue(intTestSCACValue)`

Comment: @Kinote That doesn't work with *any* `Dictionary`. The first 2 are `String`s, the last one is an `Integer`. The key is stored as a hash, so the type has to match.

Comment: Well don't I feel dumb. This whole time I've just been using the wrong type of variable to interact with it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could always create an additional dictionary to store your `Key-Value` pairs with your `Value` as your `key` and your `key` as the `value`

```
Sub test()
Dim dSCAC As Object
Dim dSCACArr As Object
Dim varOtherSCAC As String
Dim key
Dim varSCAC


Set dSCAC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dSCACArr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dSCAC.Add "AAAA", 1
dSCAC.Add "BBBB", 2
dSCAC.Add "CCCC", 3
dSCAC.Add "DDDD", 4

For Each key In dSCAC.Keys
    dSCACArr.Add dSCAC(key), key
Next

For Each varSCAC In dSCAC.Keys
    If dSCAC(varSCAC) Mod 2 Then
            Debug.Print "Odd " & "PAPS"
            varOtherSCAC = dSCACArr(dSCAC(varSCAC) + 1)
            Debug.Print "Opposite SCAC is " & varOtherSCAC

            Else
            Debug.Print "Even " & " PARS"
            varOtherSCAC = dSCACArr(dSCAC(varSCAC) - 1)
            Debug.Print "Opposite SCAC is " & varOtherSCAC
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This yielded results

```
Odd PAPS
Opposite SCAC is BBBB
Even  PARS
Opposite SCAC is AAAA
Odd PAPS
Opposite SCAC is DDDD
Even  PARS
Opposite SCAC is CCCC
```

**EDIT:**

`For Each varSCAC In dSCAC.Keys...Next` is only included for proof of concept.

Comment: `ReDim dSCACArr(Application.Min(dSCAC.Items) To Application.Max(dSCAC.Items))`                                          seems to cause Run-Time Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. I don't know why my brain went straight to Excel functions. You could bypass the array method by just using another dictionary. I've modified my code to reflect that.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for the help! Say my search returned a value of 3, how could I make that call CCCC?