# How would I call WebView2 and other modern winmd features in VBA

Tags: vba, winmd, webview2

I would like to embed a modern WebView2 component (Edge Chromium Browser Control) inside an old-style VBA UserForm.

I surmise that I would need the following installed on the system:

- Edge Chromium Broswer
- Webview2 SDK

While I have the Edge Chromium Browser installed I am unsure how to install the Webview2 SDK outside of the context of a specific Visual Studio Project. To use it in a VBA solution it needs to reference some sort of global system-wide file?

Then, apparently the type library which contains the functionality we need to embed the Edge browser is `Windows.Web.winmd`. I presume I would need to "reference" that in some way but I am not sure how...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Late Binding vs Early Binding in VBA - (CreateObject() vs New)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583705/late-binding-vs-early-binding-in-vba-createobject-vs-new)

Comment: @buran do the winmd files behave the same to VBA as COM controls as long as you can reference a file?

Comment: Your question is "I presume I would need to "reference" that in some way but I am not sure how..." - and the link explains the two possibilities - early and late binding. i.e. to use a control on the form

Comment: I am well acquainted with early and late binding. What string should I use for late binding via `CreateObject`? I tried `Windows.Web` but this failed?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found to answering this question is the following set of dlls:

http://vbrichclient.com/#/en/Downloads.htm