# How to add a WebView2 Control (To replace the old unsupported WebBrowser Control) into VBA form in 2022?

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, webview2

I want to add a control to a VBA form that displays a preview of an Excel 365 online file once the user clicks on the file name in a list. I did this successfully in the past using WebBrowser Control:

[image]

Now the problem is that this WebBrowser control is based on the extremely old Microsoft Explorer 11. Accordingly as of March 2022 this control stopped previewing Excel 365 online files and instead is showing a blank page. So it is working, but not properly since it is based on a very old technology.

I did some research and found out that this control has been replaced by Microsoft WebView2 which is much more modern but I cannot find a reference for it at all in VBA and don't know how to add this control to my VBA form.

Can someone let me know how to display webpages properly on a VBA form in 2022? Thanks! :-)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69180774/11683