How can I correct this VBA to properly scrape the owner's name, given the property address in column A?
Hi I am trying use VBA to look property tax records off of. I'd like to return the owner of a property in column B, given the address is column A.
https://publictax.smith-county.com/Search/Results?
The code I've developed will go to the above URL and successfully:

Change the drop down on the left to "Property Address"
Paste the address and then click the search button on the right


My code is having difficulty returning to Column B the owner's full name on the next page.

Sub GetOwnerNames()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim address As String
    Dim ownerName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cardBodies As Object
    Dim cardBody As Object
    Dim smallElements As Object
    Dim smallElement As Object
    Dim locationFound As Boolean
    Dim ownerElements As Object
    Dim ownerElement As Object
    Dim siblingElement As Object

    ' Create a new Internet Explorer instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    If IE Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not create Internet Explorer instance", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    IE.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want to see the IE window

    ' Set the worksheet and find the last row with data in column A
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the first row is a header
        address = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If address <> "" Then
            ' Navigate to the search page
            IE.Navigate "https://publictax.smith-county.com/search"
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

            ' Select "Property Address" from the dropdown
            Set dropdown = IE.document.getElementById("Query.SearchField")
            If dropdown Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Could not find dropdown element", vbCritical
                GoTo Cleanup
            End If
            dropdown.Value = 5 ' Value for "Property Address"
            dropdown.FireEvent "onchange"
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

            ' Find the search box, input the address, and submit the search
            Set searchBox = IE.document.getElementById("Query.SearchText")
            If searchBox Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Could not find search box element", vbCritical
                GoTo Cleanup
            End If
            searchBox.Value = address
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

            ' Click the search button
            Set searchButton = IE.document.querySelector("button.btn.btn-primary.col[type=submit]")
            If searchButton Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Could not find search button element", vbCritical
                GoTo Cleanup
            End If
            searchButton.Click
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

            ' Wait for the results to load completely
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

            ' Extract elements to find "Property Location" and "Owner Name"
            ownerName = "Not Found"
            Set cardBodies = IE.document.querySelectorAll("div.card-body")
            If cardBodies Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Could not find card-body elements", vbCritical
                GoTo Cleanup
            End If

            For Each cardBody In cardBodies
                locationFound = False
                Set smallElements = cardBody.getElementsByTagName("small")
                For Each smallElement In smallElements
                    If InStr(Trim(smallElement.innerText), "Property Location") > 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "Property Location found: " & Trim(smallElement.innerText)
                        If Not smallElement.NextElementSibling Is Nothing Then
                            If InStr(Trim(smallElement.NextElementSibling.innerText), address) > 0 Then
                                Debug.Print "Address matched: " & Trim(smallElement.NextElementSibling.innerText)
                                locationFound = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next smallElement

                ' If the property location is found, get the owner name
                If locationFound Then
                    Set ownerElements = cardBody.getElementsByTagName("strong")
                    For Each ownerElement In ownerElements
                        If Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "" And Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "Account Number" And _
                           Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "Total Due" And Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "Owner Name" And _
                           Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "Type" And Trim(ownerElement.innerText) <> "Property Location" Then
                            ownerName = ownerElement.innerText
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ownerElement
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cardBody

            ' Write the owner name back to the worksheet
            ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ownerName
        End If
    Next i

    Cleanup:
    ' Clean up
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox "Owner names have been updated.", vbInformation
End Sub


I've tried using AI to help correct the code, however The VBA either returns "not found", or it will successfully, but incorrectly grab the account number that you see in the screenshot below. How can I adjust this VBA to grab the name "Walker Janis Kimberly" and past it in column B, before moving onto the next address?

Which OS are you using?

Internet Explorer. I apparently have to download other stuff to use Chrome or Edge. In IE, I can see that the VBA does correctly pull up the webpage, change the dropdown, paste the address, and push enter. On the second page, it will either grab the account number and not the name, or return "Not Found". There's some issue with the code not associating Owner Name with Janis Walker. I have no idea.

OS = Operating System. Support for IE ended in 2022 so from Windows 10 (I think) it's likely to not work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179127/will-vbas-internet-control-function-after-ie-11-end-of-life-in-jun-22
Common "wisdom" seems to suggest moving to Selenium

Gotcha, that might be the issue. Is this something I can get for free?

I think so - have a look - https://www.selenium.dev/about/
